# Getting associated records in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This one should be easy.

I have @restaurants which contains a selected number of records from the Restaurant model. Each Restaurant has one or more locations. I would like to store in an instance variable all of the locations corresponding with all of the restaurants in @restaurants.

This doesn't work:

```
@locations = @restaurants.locations
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@locations = Location.where(restaurant_id: @restaurants).all
```